# How to add the sum in a Webform Report?

Tags: webforms, log-messages

I would like to have the total sum of a number field in a report created with [Webform Report](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_report).

How can I get the total sum of that column table?

Comment: I have found a way to do that. Instead of webform report. I can use Views and Views Aggregator Plus to display the submission data. I can put a function sum to the selected fields.

Comment: I would love to know more about this, Is there some link I can read more about it. Also you can answer your own question and accept it as well to close this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the [Webform Report](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_report) module, you can use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) to display the submission data. You can use the aggregation function ***sum*** for the selected fields (to aggregate your webform submission results tables).

Credits: [Waluyo Adi Siswanto](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/36666/waluyo-adi-siswanto).